# What's the proper way to change views in Ember, based on an action from the controller?

Tags: ember.js

I currently have an action set up in a template for which the purpose is tracking a user's selection, and then changing pages based on that selection.

This is the applicable portion of my `router`:

```
this.resource('simpleSearch', function() {
    this.resource('simpleSearchOption', {path: ':simpleSearchOption_id'});
```

Here's the action:

```
<div {{action "select" this}} class="questiontile">
```

And here's the controller:

```
App.SimpleSearchOptionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    needs: ["simpleSearch"],
    simpleSearch: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.simpleSearch"),

    actions: {
        select: function(optionId) {
            var nextOptionId = parseInt(this.get("id")) + 1;
            var numOfOptions = this.get('simpleSearch').get('model').length;
            if(nextOptionId < numOfOptions) {
                console.log('going to next option');

                  /** What do I do here?
                   *  This is my current implementation, 
                   *  and it works, but is it proper?   
                   */
                  this.transitionToRoute('/simpleSearch/' + nextOptionId);

            }
        }
    }
});
```

The next page is basically the next index up an array of objects which is the model for the parent route/controller/view.

How I'm doing it at the moment is working - but is that proper?  Is it 'Ember idiomatic'?

Comment: Interesting! I should have looked closer at the documentation.  I guess I should RTFM more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about previous post, accidentally deleted it!
The transitionToRoute takes two arguments, first is the resource/route name and the second is the model. So this should work

```
actions: {
    select: function(optionId) {
        var nextOptionId = parseInt(this.get("id")) + 1;
        this.store.find('simpleSearch', nextOptionId).then(function(model){
              this.transitionToRoute('simpleSearchOption', model); 
        });
        //OR MAYBE YOU COULD GET IT FROM THE PARENT CONTROLLER??
      /*
       MAYBE
       this.get('simpleSearch.content').forEach(function(model){
             if(model.get('id') === nextOptionId){ do transition}
              else{ alert some msg!! }
       })
      */
    }
 }
```

More info here : http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute

Comment: That's alright - thank you for the information!  I'm not using ember-data though, so no `store` for me.